# How to get type hint in php array similar to java or typescript?

Tags: php, wordpress, types, type-hinting, strong-typing

I read various articles claiming that now php-8 also is strongly type language
https://medium.com/codex/php-became-strongly-typed-66f2b2ae917. Since I work with typescript, i was looking for same IDE experience but when I recently started to working on WordPress, ad I found that mostly associative arrays are used instead of objects for passing arguments in WordPress method like

```
 register_post_type('event',array(
    'show_in_rest'=>true,
    'supports'=>array('title','editor','excerpt'),
    'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'events'),
    'has_archive'=>true,
    'public'=>true,
    'labels'=>array(
        'name'=>'Events',
        'add_new_item'=>"Add New Event",
        'edit_item'=>"Edit Event",
        'all_items'=>"All Events",
        
        'singular_name'=>'Event'
    ),
    'menu_icon'=>'dashicons-calendar'
));
```

Since in java and typescript i mostly use object to pass data thus ide provide very nice hinting system.
Now for php-8 arrays, IDE provide no auto-completion like in typescript or in java.
Is there a way to get same type hint experience with php as it is in  typescript or in java.

Comment: You didn't mention which IDE you are using.

Comment: I am using vscode IDE

Comment: You'll have to install the vscode extension for php. by default vscode doesn't do anything for php, you'll need the additional extensions for php code sniffing, formatting, hints, autocomplete, etc.

Comment: Extensions are already install, my question is sending data more like a object rather than associative array in which we to hardcord almost every value in string thus no auto-completion. Auto-completion is working fine for other and functions. Associative  Arrays of php are weekly type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has been around for almost two decades, long before php 8. Many sites still run on php 5.6 (!!!). Sad to say, it uses these associative arrays rather than strongly typed objects for its functions requiring data-structure parameters.